# How to call a function inside a binary in c without knowing the function's symbol name?

Tags: c, java-native-interface, elf

How can i call a function(or subroutine) in a binary from C without knowing it's symbol name? I only know the address.

Comment: I would say: use a function pointer and set its value. then call the function.

Comment: Which one is it, [tag:c] or [tag:c++]?  Those are completely different languages.

Comment: @HenriMenke c. my bad, i'll remove the c++ tag to avoid misunderstandings

Comment: Is your function that does the calling going to be part of the executable?  If so, why doesn't it know the name, and how will it find the pointer address?  If your function that does the calling isn't part of the executable, how is it getting invoked.  In general, a function in one process cannot call a function in another process without going through elaborate setup (RPC -- remote procedure call).  How do you know the interface to use for the function whose name you don't know?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Embedded system with binary code in ROM maybe?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the function isn't going to be apart of the executable, and it will be invoked via the JNI

Comment: @user8398347 Maybe you can add some context - how/why do you know the address but not the name. Any specific system?

Comment: @4386427: that might be relevant; it would certainly change expectations.  There probably wouldn't be ASLR to worry about, amongst other things.  If you have a function `void perform_magic(void);` for which you know the calling sequence (prototype) and the address where it lives is 0x876543012, you can play with death and write something ghastly like: `void (*function)(void) = (void (*)(void))0x876543012; (*function)();` where the first line declares a pointer to the correct function type and coerces the address to the right type of pointer. There are many opportunities for things to go wrong.

Comment: Add the info about JNI to the question.  You need to explain which function you're trying to execute (outlining the code).  Maybe you should add the JNI tag to get people experienced in that to help you.  It's not a topic I reckon to know anything about (at least, not enough to be able to answer).

Comment: @4386427 there will be ASLR unfortunately since i'm dealing with android(the targeted binary and my binary will be within the same android application.)

Comment: JNI is hopefully not relevant here. If you can add a native lib of yours that will perform the discussed function call, you can ignore the JVM presence.

Comment: JNA can do that directly from Java if you don't want to write an extra lib.